# Tenho como atualizar a biblioteca Mono.Android no Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, mono, xamarin-studio

Estou tendo alguns problemas e creio que se consegui-se atualizar a biblioteca mono teria acesso a novas funcionalidade, alguem conseguiu fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Novas funcionalidade são obtidas através da atualização das bibliotecas,
por padrão são automáticas e você é notificado. Caso queira checar manualmente: `Tools`->`Options`
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Atualize também os pacotes em: `Tools`->`Nuget Package Manager`
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]